# ¿Por qué estos dos queries me arrojan conteos distintos?

Tags: mysql

Ayudenme a entender porque estos dos querys me arrojan valores diferentes en la columna count? El primer query me arroja el conteo correcto, el segundo no

1er query

```
    select company_id, count(company_id) 
from shipments 
where company_id = 162 and status_id != 4 
group by company_id
```

2do query

```
    SELECT
        c.id AS company_id,
        c.name AS company_name,
        c.locale_id AS country_id,
        c.created_at,
        e.name AS ecommerce_name,
        COUNT(s.company_id) as ships
    FROM
        companies AS c
    LEFT JOIN 
        shops AS sh ON c.id = sh.company_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        ecommerce AS e ON e.id = sh.ecommerce_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        shipments AS s ON c.id = s.company_id and s.status_id != 4
    WHERE 
        s.company_id = 162
    GROUP BY 
        s.company_id
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Saludos, Revisa; por que parte de la tabla companies en la que usas varias tablas; ademas que el status_id != 4 en la primera lo tienes en el where y en el segundo no.

Comment: Son dos consultas totalmente distintas, es como que una cuenta manzanas y otra repuestos de automóvil, además sin conocer la lógica de negocios, que significa cada tabla es imposible darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primero revisa la tabla shipments sin más, filtra de todos los registros los que tienen un company_id, los que no tienen un status_id. Luego, ese conjunto lo agrupa por company_id y genera el conteo agrupado.

El segundo hace varios LEFT JOINS de companies con otras tablas (incluyendo shipments) para armar el conjunto de registros sobre los que va a trabajar.
Va a armar unas filas largas con datos de las 4 tablas. Si hay un registro en companies sin registros asociados en ecommerce, shops o shipments, va a afectar el conteo agrupado.

Sin ver tus datos es imposible dar una respuesta concreta, pero lo que se puede decir con la información en la pregunta es que el conteo se va a afectar por los registros generados al hacer los LEFT JOIN.

Si corres la segunda consulta sin agrupar y sin hacer SUM, vas a ver por qué el conteo es diferente.

Comment: Al fin y al cabo, un join es un producto cartesiano de dos tablas. Cuando haces múltiple joins en una query, el número de resultados con el que trabajas crece exponencialmente en base al número de datos en cada tabla.